# work with existing project in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a job to add some functions to a project that someone worked with it.
but when I load the project everything gives me an error.
also, all dependencies were not found.

[image: this is an image of some controller]

Comment: Do you have the .sln and .csproj files? If you have the .sln (solution) file, open that. If you only have the .csproj (project) file, open that. Otherwise, you're going to need to rebuild the project with all its references, etc. (easiest option might be to create a new one and copy the desired files in).

Comment: @Llama I have the .sln file, but I think the problem is with the references. all of them have a yellow triangle

Comment: I would suggest going through and re-adding them all manually. NuGet packages can be done via the NuGet package manager (see VS' "Tools" menu)

Answer (score 1):

this means dll that needed by project not found in your project.

- first check the framework version of the project and be sure that you installed the same version of framework ( you can open .csproj file with notepad and check the version)
- second restore nuget package of your project (with dotnet restore command or visual studio nuget manager)